# Division result is not correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
CGFloat result=100/126;
NSLog(@"%0.5f",result);
```

the output of above code is 0.00000 but when i check it on calculator then the value is 0.79365. what is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is as both operands of division are integers, integer division is performed and its result is 0. To get proper value you need to make sure that at least one of your operands is floating point number:

```
CGFloat result=100.0f/126;
```

Comment: can you explain or give any web link that why it gives 0 in integer division.

Comment: @Developer: In integer division 100/126 is 0 remainder 100.

Answer (score 1):

May be because your variables are integers. Do this

```
CGFloat result=100.0/126.0;
NSLog(@"%0.5f",result);
```