# Easy math function with int64_t not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do you divide two integers and get a decimal answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976011/how-do-you-divide-two-integers-and-get-a-decimal-answer)

This is probably really easy but I can't find the solution. I'm not a "real" programmer...

I'm storing number and scores on my app using int_64.

```
 .h

 int64_t score;

 @property (nonatomic, assign) int64_t score;

.m

 @synthesize score;
```

Here is the math:

```
self.score = 7/3;
```

The result is "2", instead of "2.33333...". I should use use something different from int_64, but what?

I wanted the result to be "2,33", with two digits after the comma. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543661/whats-wrong-with-this-division

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459351/objective-c-division-of-two-ints

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857438/division-result-is-not-correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` stores whole numbers, also called integers. For calculations with a fractional part use `double`.

Also, it's better to fix the number of digits is when formatting for display. For example:

```
double score = 7.0/3.0;
NSString *strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", score];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `double` to store decimal numbers instead of `int`.
If you try to store a decimal number in an int it will get rounded.

> @property (nonatomic, assign) double score;

Comment: Thx, but this is giving me the answer "2.000000".

Comment: This only fixes half of the issue. The integer division is still done because both operands are integers.

Comment: You can find how to limit a double to 2 decimals here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113408/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places